# Python: capturing both of sys.stdout and sys.stderr as a log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-2.6, stderr

Roughly speaking, I want to port this to pure Python:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    python test.py
} &> /tmp/test.log
```

This didn't work for some unknown reasons:

```
import os.path, sys
import tempfile

with open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "test.log"), "a") as fp:
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = fp
    raise Exception("I'm dying")
```

The resulting `test.log` was empty (and I didn't see anything on my console,) when I tested it with Python 2.6.6, Python 2.7.8 and Python 3.4.2 on CentOS x86_64.

But Ideally I'd like a solution for Python 2.6.

(For now, it's tolerable to clutter the log file with intermixed output from `stdout` and `stderr` or multithreading, as long as any data won't simply disappear into a blackhole.)

**Show me a concise and portable solution which is confirmed to work with an exception stack trace on `sys.stderr`.**  (Preferably something other than `os.dup2`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: @Rishav That article surely gives me some general insights but I'm looking for a specific solution to my specific problem.

Comment: I works if instead of using `with` you just assign the file to `fp`

Comment: @eli You're right, so the stack trace is printed outside of `with`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import os, os.path, sys, tempfile

old_out = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
old_err = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())
with open(os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), "test.log"), "a") as fp:
    fd = fp.fileno()
    os.dup2(fd, sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(fd, sys.stderr.fileno())
    print("Testing")
    print('testing errs', file=sys.stderr)
    raise Exception("I'm dying")
```

The **future** is just for cleaner handling of Python2 or Python3 with the same example.  (I've also changed the *raise* statement to instantiate an exception, strings as exceptions have been deprecated for a long time and they're not properly supported under Python3).

The old_* values are just if we wanted to restore our original stdout and/or stderr after using our redirected file.

Comment: Thanks, `os.dup2` doesn't actually look like a bad solution

Answer (score 2):

You can use a method like this one:

```
import traceback
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def output_to_file(filepath, write_mode='w'):
    stdout_orig = None
    stderr_orig = None

    stdout_orig = sys.stdout
    stderr_orig = sys.stderr

    f = open(filepath, write_mode)

    sys.stdout = f
    sys.stderr = f

    try:
        yield
    except:
        info = sys.exc_info()
        f.write('\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(*info)))

    f.close()

    sys.stdout = stdout_orig
    sys.stderr = stderr_orig
```

And the the usage is:

```
with output_to_file('test.log'):
    print('hello')
    raise Exception('I am dying')
```

And the `cat test.log` produces:

```
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-a3b702c7b741>", line 20, in outputi_to_file
    yield

  File "<ipython-input-4-f879d82580b2>", line 3, in <module>
    raise Exception('I am dying')

Exception: I am dying
```

Comment: In what sort of environment did you **confirm** 
`with output_to_file('test.log'):
    raise Exception("I'm dying")` worked?  `test.log` was empy in my environment.

Comment: You are right. didn't test for exceptions. Fixed it. See it now

Comment: Your approach is interesting but there's a problem with it; usually, when a thrown exception is not caught, the return code of the script is set to 1 rather than 0, indicating an abnormal completion of the script.  But under your `try...catch...`, it won't happen.  This can make a difference in shell scripting.

Comment: So I got this variant, but it assumes an uncaught exception from the wrapped code block terminates the entire script.  I think it kills half of the advantages of your approach.

```def output_to_file(filepath, write_mode='w'):
  stdout_orig = sys.stdout
  stderr_orig = sys.stderr

  with open(filepath, write_mode) as f:

    sys.stdout = f
    sys.stderr = f

    try:
      yield
    except:
      info = sys.exc_info()
      f.write('\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(*info)))
      sys.exit(1)
    finally:
      sys.stdout = stdout_orig
      sys.stderr = stderr_orig```

Comment: Another option is to reraise the exception (or use only finally depending on your need), and add a try except in your main function, doing one `sys.exit` for all your code. Keeping this function "clean"

Answer (score 2):

Remember that file objects are closed after `with` blocks :)

Use simply this:

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open("test.log","w")
raise Exception("Dead")
```

Content of test.log after exit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise Exception("Dead")
Exception: Dead
```

Comment: Hmmmm I confirmed there was data in `test.log`

Comment: @nodakai what do you mean?

Comment: So far it seems like a valid solution to my problem but I'd like to check if Python can ensure any data won't be lost.